# login register in c

Tags: c++, file-io, authentication

I am writing a program in C++ that is based on a simple log in/register system but involving the file input/output.

One idea is to create a new file for every user who signs up, put/update the user's data in that file. But it does not seems to be ideal as there could be thousands of users.

Another idea is to put the user information in JSON format something like:

> {
>     "moin" : {
>     "pw" : "moinpw",
>     "email" : "moin@example.com",
>     "name" : "Muhammad Moin Uddin"
>     }
>   }

and then write/update it. It would require a single file to be served as database.
For this purpose I searched for JSON parser and tried [JsonCpp](http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net) but as I'm a learner in C++ field so had no luck in running that program.

I was trying the code below:

> int main()
>   {
>       Json::Value root;

```
   ifstream file("json.json");
   file >> root;
   cout << root;

system("pause");

return 0;
```

> }

But got so many errors. I had included all the header files needed.

Please suggest some better solution or just guide me make this JSON thing run.

Thanks in advance.

> http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at the SQLite package especially if you are thinking you will have thousands of users (records).

Here is [An Introduction To the SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Comment: No, I can't use any database. As I already mentioned I have to use file system.

Comment: @user1623664 SQLite does use the file system.  It is a package that puts an SQL interface on to flat files stored in a file system.  It can be used as an embedded database or through a database connection driver using an interface such as ADO with the proper drivers.

Comment: No you don't understand. I have to make it simple without involving and database. I just have to read and write to files.